# How to make report of form saved data in Sitecore 9.3?

Tags: sitecore-forms, mvc-forms

I have created a form in the site experience platform, and my form data is saving in `sitecore_ExperienceForms database`, How can I create a report with filter functionality in Sitecore 9.3. Anyone, please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will have to create a custom speak UI or aspx page which would connect to experienceforms Db tables FormEntry and fielddata and display the same. you could use SSRS on the aspx page for data display

Comment: Thanks @AbhayDharHow for you reply. the same can be implement in MVC.Is there no option within sitecore to create the same.could you please send me some refrence doc.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no option, only export data option is available. I dont have any reference doc